# Correct way to render and display array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to display different arrays of objects from a rest api. I have tried it by doing the following first:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React', 
      awsApiData: [],
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/data')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({awsApiData: data.home}, () => console.log(data.home)))
  }


  render() {
    const data = this.state.awsApiData;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data).map(e => {
          return <div>{data[e].title}<br />{data[e].body}<br /></div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I know this is not really the correct way, as I am fetching the array at the `ComponentDidMount` level. Where I want to be able to do it at the `Render` level.

My api looks like this:

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "title": "John Doe title",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "about": [
    {
      "title": "John is the main part 1",
      "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
      "image": "image/example.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I should call the api as follows:

```
 componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app mounted');
        fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/data')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({awsApiData: data}, () => console.log(data)))
 }
```

Then in the render method access each array.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your code is ok and works as intended. When you use `setState`, you already have the data available in `render`. What is it that you face issues with?

Comment: So I would like to access the `home array` and the `about array`, In the render method

Comment: That would be `data.home`, and `data.about` inside `render`

Comment: So where abouts would that be?

Comment: Are you just looking for a method that gets every element of objects without knowing the keys of object?

Comment: Yes, that could work

Answer (score 1):

You do want to do it at `componentDidMount` - you don't want to change state in your render method or you'll have problems!

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is more correct, because it is an object of arrays, you need to normalize it, you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` to flatten the data and then loop it:

```
Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  return data[key][0].title
})
```

This will show every title.

Please note that this is just a very straightforward example, it would be better to have another function normalizing the data, so you end with an simple array of data.

You might also ask yourself where is better to do this normalization? Usually it is better before setting the state, so in the `then` function, but in practice it doesn't matter most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

No worries. ComponentDidMount is the best place for API calls. 
Or if you have any other concerns, please let me know. I will help you.

Comment: Thanks, how would I access the individual arrays, in the render method though?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. 
Once you got the response from the API, you can store it in the state.
The state values are accessible inside render by using this.state.[the value].

In order to access the arrays, you can use map.

{Object.keys(data).map(key => {
          return <div>{data[key].title}<br />{data[key].body}<br /></div>;
        })}